# How can I make VMware forget a "remember my choice" value for a device?

Tags: linux, vmware

I have an iPhone which I would like to connect to a Windows 10 guest on a Linux Mint 18.2 host via VMware.

I believe that in the past I made a choice to connect the phone to the Linux host (and remember that selection), and now I don't know how to change it to the Windows guest.

How can I reassign or undo this kind of preference?

**--UPDATE--**

`~/.vmware/preferences` reads:

```
.encoding = "UTF-8"
pref.lastUpdateCheckSec = "1509994981"
pref.keyboardAndMouse.vmHotKey.enabled = "FALSE"
pref.keyboardAndMouse.vmHotKey.count = "0"
vmWizard.guestKey = "ubuntu-64"
vmWizard.installMediaType = "iso"
pref.vmplayer.fullscreenMRU.count = "0"
pref.vmplayer.fullscreen.autohide = "TRUE"
hints.hideAll = "FALSE"
hint.vmui.showAllUSBDevs = "FALSE"
pref.sharedFolder.maxNum = "1"
pref.sharedFolder0.vmPath = "/vm/#f320a9b6ef9f2616/"
pref.sharedFolder0.guestName = "jonathan"
pref.sharedFolder0.hostPath = "/Users/jonathan"
pref.sharedFolder0.enabled = "TRUE"
```

The VMX file reads,

```
.encoding = "UTF-8"
config.version = "8"
virtualHW.version = "12"
scsi0.present = "TRUE"
scsi0.virtualDev = "lsisas1068"
sata0.present = "TRUE"
memsize = "4096"
mem.hotadd = "TRUE"
scsi0:0.present = "TRUE"
scsi0:0.fileName = "Virtual Disk.vmdk"
sata0:1.present = "TRUE"
sata0:1.fileName = "/Users/christos/Downloads/Win10_1607_English_x64.iso"
sata0:1.deviceType = "cdrom-image"
ethernet0.present = "TRUE"
ethernet0.connectionType = "nat"
ethernet0.virtualDev = "e1000e"
ethernet0.wakeOnPcktRcv = "FALSE"
ethernet0.addressType = "generated"
ethernet0.linkStatePropagation.enable = "TRUE"
usb.present = "TRUE"
ehci.present = "TRUE"
ehci.pciSlotNumber = "34"
usb_xhci.present = "TRUE"
sound.present = "TRUE"
sound.virtualDev = "hdaudio"
sound.fileName = "-1"
sound.autodetect = "TRUE"
mks.enable3d = "TRUE"
svga.graphicsMemoryKB = "1048576"
serial0.present = "TRUE"
serial0.fileType = "thinprint"
pciBridge0.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge4.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge4.virtualDev = "pcieRootPort"
pciBridge4.functions = "8"
pciBridge5.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge5.virtualDev = "pcieRootPort"
pciBridge5.functions = "8"
pciBridge6.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge6.virtualDev = "pcieRootPort"
pciBridge6.functions = "8"
pciBridge7.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge7.virtualDev = "pcieRootPort"
pciBridge7.functions = "8"
vmci0.present = "TRUE"
hpet0.present = "TRUE"
usb.vbluetooth.startConnected = "TRUE"
sensor.accelerometer = "pass-through"
sensor.ambientLight = "pass-through"
sensor.compass = "pass-through"
sensor.gyrometer = "pass-through"
sensor.inclinometer = "pass-through"
sensor.location = "pass-through"
sensor.orientation = "pass-through"
tools.syncTime = "TRUE"
displayName = "Windows 10"
guestOS = "windows9-64"
nvram = "Windows 10 x64 6.nvram"
virtualHW.productCompatibility = "hosted"
tools.upgrade.policy = "upgradeAtPowerCycle"
powerType.powerOff = "soft"
powerType.powerOn = "soft"
powerType.suspend = "soft"
powerType.reset = "soft"
extendedConfigFile = "Windows 10 x64 6.vmxf"
numvcpus = "4"
cpuid.coresPerSocket = "4"
uuid.bios = "56 4d 2f 22 1d 68 e8 01-d5 6c 39 09 02 8b 5b fc"
uuid.location = "56 4d 6c d6 37 08 ff 96-79 bf d3 76 94 3d 49 26"
replay.supported = "FALSE"
replay.filename = ""
migrate.hostlog = "./Windows 10 x64 6-ff72f73e.hlog"
scsi0:0.redo = ""
pciBridge0.pciSlotNumber = "17"
pciBridge4.pciSlotNumber = "21"
pciBridge5.pciSlotNumber = "22"
pciBridge6.pciSlotNumber = "23"
pciBridge7.pciSlotNumber = "24"
scsi0.pciSlotNumber = "160"
usb.pciSlotNumber = "32"
ethernet0.pciSlotNumber = "192"
sound.pciSlotNumber = "33"
usb_xhci.pciSlotNumber = "224"
vmci0.pciSlotNumber = "35"
sata0.pciSlotNumber = "36"
scsi0.sasWWID = "50 05 05 62 1d 68 e8 00"
ethernet0.generatedAddress = "00:0C:29:8B:5B:FC"
ethernet0.generatedAddressOffset = "0"
vmci0.id = "42687484"
vm.genid = "5911851917142158605"
vm.genidX = "-5071518348813440210"
monitor.phys_bits_used = "42"
vmotion.checkpointFBSize = "4194304"
vmotion.checkpointSVGAPrimarySize = "33554432"
cleanShutdown = "TRUE"
softPowerOff = "FALSE"
usb_xhci:6.speed = "2"
usb_xhci:6.present = "TRUE"
usb_xhci:6.deviceType = "hub"
usb_xhci:6.port = "6"
usb_xhci:6.parent = "-1"
usb_xhci:7.speed = "4"
usb_xhci:7.present = "TRUE"
usb_xhci:7.deviceType = "hub"
usb_xhci:7.port = "7"
usb_xhci:7.parent = "-1"
sata0:1.startConnected = "FALSE"
svga.guestBackedPrimaryAware = "TRUE"8
gui.fitGuestUsingNativeDisplayResolution = "TRUE"
tools.remindInstall = "FALSE"
toolsInstallManager.updateCounter = "4"
checkpoint.vmState = "Windows 10 x64 6-b2dbd261.vmss"
gui.lastPoweredViewMode = "fullscreen"
gui.fullScreenAtPowerOn = "TRUE"
gui.viewModeAtPowerOn = "fullscreen"
numa.autosize.vcpu.maxPerVirtualNode = "4"
numa.autosize.cookie = "40001"
toolsInstallManager.lastInstallError = "0"
acpi.smbiosVersion2.7 = "FALSE"
acpi.mouseVMW0003 = "FALSE"
unity.wasCapable = "TRUE"
floppy0.present = "FALSE"
usb_xhci:4.present = "TRUE"
usb_xhci:4.deviceType = "hid"
usb_xhci:4.port = "4"8
usb_xhci:4.parent = "-1"
```

N.B. I also fired up another Windows VM, and when I attached the phone it went straight to Linux without asking about either VM. *Meaning that this is probably a setting for VMware or (possibly) Linux Mint, rather than a per-guest configuration.* I had changed the `~/vmware/preferences` by deleting one line with information scent; I could not observe any difference.

Thanks,

Comment: If you power on the VM and explicitly connect the iPhone to the guest, does it not remember the setting?  If not, then the setting probably is either in your preferences file (`~/.vmware/preferences`) or possibly in the VM's configuration file (the `.vmx` file in the VM directory).  I don't remember offhand where it is, but you probably should be able to figure out by inspecting them with a text editor.

Comment: @jamesdlin Thank you; I hadn't found anything helpful along those lines. I've edited the question to include the contents of both text files.